# Confirmation box in javascript on button click and if return true perform click event of same button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having a asp.net button control and a javascript confirmation box which is executed on that button click. If the javascript returns true than only perform click event of button..

HTML:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="454px" CausesValidation="true" onfocus="ddlSelect()"></asp:TextBox>


    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveSend" CssClass="myButton" runat="server" Text="Save & Send"
                                        OnClientClick="javascript:return SubjectEmpty()" OnClick="btnSaveSend_Click" />
```

Javascript:

```
    function SubjectEmpty() {
    var subject = document.getElementById("<%=txtSubject.ClientID%>").value;
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to send mail:" + subject + " ? We shell        check for the availability..");
        if (result == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void btnSaveSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

The problem is even if I select cancel it executes btnSaveSend_click()

Comment: the shortest way to write it is `return confirm('Are you serious?');` But you say the page gets posted to the server and the event executes...so why do you think that is so?

Comment: I know about this way but problem is that I want to get text entered in txtSubject. And about posting to server I debugged it.

Comment: so what is the problem on that front you are facing?

Comment: I dont want to call click event if user clicks on Cancel

Comment: That is expected behavior. In other words, and greatly simplified, `OnClientClick="javascript:return false;"` should **not** trigger a postback. You need to debug and find out why `confirm(...)` is actually returning `true` in your case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys my mistake..

I had used ajax control in my page. So it was performing click event even if I click on cancel. I didnt knew it earlier that this was due to ajax. So I got other way out:

```
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to send mail:" + subject + " of type "+type+" on " + sendDate + " at " + hour + ":" + min + ":00.. We shell check for the availability..")) {
            document.getElementById('<%=btnSaveSend.ClientID%>').disabled = true;                
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  function SubjectEmpty() {
         var subject = document.getElementById("<%=txtSubject.ClientID%>").value;
         if (confirm("Are you sure you want to send mail:" + subject + " ? We shell                    
         check for the availability..")) 
         {
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return false;
         }
  }
```

Comment: @Ami its just the usage of if condition which prevents its from firing the `OnClick` event .

Comment: This is also not working. Don't understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this..You should add a `return false;` to block the server event from firing..

```
function SubjectEmpty() {
    var subject = document.getElementById("<%=txtSubject.ClientID%>").value;
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to send mail:" + subject + " ? We shall  check for the availability..");
     if (result == true) {
         return true;
     }
      else
     {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It will fire the OnClick event in else part too.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Java script function like below. It will help you.

```
function SubjectEmpty() {
    var subject = document.getElementById("<%=txtSubject.ClientID%>").value;
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to send mail:" + subject + " ? We shell        check for the availability..");
     if (result == true) {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```